# How to pass value from one class to another class GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm new in JAVA programming but how do I pass variable/value from one class A to seconnd class B where B is my GUI and A is logic to display the players? I need to print the players name in GUI to lblPlayer label.

Class A:

```
    package driverPkg;

    import game.Card;
    import game.CardsUI;
    import game.players.CardPlayer;


    public class GameConsole implements CardsUI {


        public void currentCard(CardPlayer[] player) {


            for (CardPlayer p : player) {
            // here somehow return p.getName() and pass to the GUI
            }
        }
....more code not really need it
```

Class B (GUI)

```
public class CardsGameGUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CardsGameGUI frame = new CardsGameGUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public CardsGameGUI() {
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 26));
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Card Game");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 828, 556);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(102, 153, 153));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);


           JLabel lblPlayer = new JLabel("");//here i need to bring the players name
        lblPlayer.setFont(new Font("Arial One", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblPlayer.setBounds(6, 11, 49, 16);
        panel.add(lblPlayer);

...more code below not need it now
```

Thank your for your help

Comment: make B to create an instance of A and the on every paint obtains its state

Comment: sure, but any idea how do I do it :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Player class is your businness object. Add PropertyChangeSupport to this class, let CardsGameGUI implement PropertyChangeListener and add it as a listener to the player instance. Everytime you change something in the console the player will fire a property change event and you can listen and react in the gui. It's a simple observer pattern.

A simple example can be found here: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/beans/bean-property-change-event-listener/

Comment: i edited my code in the loop. but I still do know how to implement your solution :( I just need to simply pass values from one class to another.

Comment: I'm still not sure, but I think you want to control the content of the frame from the GameConsole, isn't it? You could move the main method to GameConsole. This class opens the CardsGameUI and registers the frame for each playeras a listener.